# How to match lists of two objects based on a common field using map?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, backend

```
Class AccountInfo
{
String id;
String name;
String type;
}
Class MeetingsInfo
{
String id;
String count;
Date meetingDate;
}
List<AccountInfo> accounts;
List<MeetingsInfo> meetings;
```

Here "accounts" contain details of all accounts and meetings contain all meetings of that day. How to create a new list of "AccountInfo" which contain "id" same as the "id" of meetings using "map" function?

I tried to do it this way:

```
List<AccountInfo> newAccounts = accounts.stream().map(meetings::getAccountId);
```

Please do mention if there is any optimised method than using map.

Answer (score 0):

> create a new list of "AccountInfo" which contain "id" same as the "id" of >meetings

What do want to do if id's are same, merge in a new variable ?

Comment: I want to make a list of AccountInfo which contains only those accounts whose id's are present in "meetings". Rest of the accounts must be excluded whose id's are not present in meetings. Is there any efficient way to do this without using a for loop?